# Magento 2: How to disable Minify CSS JS setting?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, developer-mode, minified-js

I went to the admin panel.

Then I went to

**Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > CSS Settings**

**Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > JavaScript Settings**

and enabled minify CSS and Javascript.

Now, CSS and JS of my website are not working.
My admin panel and the website is broken.
How do I disable this setting?

Comment: You can only disable it in developer mode

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Access your **MySQL** and use these commands:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='0' WHERE `path`='dev/js/merge_files';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='0' WHERE `path`='dev/js/enable_js_bundling';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='0' WHERE `path`='dev/js/minify_files';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='0' WHERE `path`='dev/css/merge_css_files';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='0' WHERE `path`='dev/css/minify_files';
```

Or you can use the **Magerun** in your terminal:

```
magerun config:store:set dev/js/merge_files 0
magerun config:store:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 0
magerun config:store:set dev/js/minify_files 0
magerun config:store:set dev/css/merge_css_files 0
magerun config:store:set dev/css/minify_files 0
```

---

Then run these commands to deploy again:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage deploy:mode:set developer &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy -f &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
I ran mysql script and it ran successfully.
It changed some values in table from 1 to 0.
Do i need to run setup:upgrade now?

Comment: I recommend to run all these last commands

Comment: oh, okay. Trying that.

Comment: If I'm in developer mode, I need not run `setup:static-content:deploy`.Right?

Comment: you don't need, but I recommend to run

Answer (score 24):

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/js/merge_files 0
php bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 0
php bin/magento config:set dev/js/minify_files 0
php bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 0
php bin/magento config:set dev/css/minify_files 0
```

After config set, you need to regenerate static files by using below commands.

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use Below Command for - Disable(0) / Enable(1) from SSH/Putty/CMD.**

Merge Minify JS

`php bin/magento config:set dev/js/merge_files 0`

`php bin/magento config:set dev/js/minify_files 0`

---

JS Bundling

`php bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 0`

---

Merge Minify CSS

`php bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 0`

`php bin/magento config:set dev/css/minify_files 0`

---

CSS Critical Path

`php bin/magento config:set dev/css/use_css_critical_path 0`

---

Minify HTML

`php bin/magento config:set dev/template/minify_html 0`

---

**Note: In last don't forget to run below command**

`php bin/magento cache:clean`